# How to make independent Thread sleep in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-sleep

So I start my thread like this:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(myFunction);
    thread.start();
```

And this function has a loop that needs to execute once a second:

```
   public void myFunction(){
     while(true){
         sleep?
     }
   }
```

How do I make this thread sleep without pausing my main thread?

Comment: There are _many_ posts on Stack Overflow describing `Thread.Sleep()`, which explain, just as the MSDN documentation does, that only the thread calling that method is delayed. Calling `Thread.Sleep()` in a worker thread will delay the main thread only if the main thread is actually itself waiting on the worker thread for some reason. If you have tried calling `Thread.Sleep()` and find it blocking a thread you didn't want it to block, you need to post a question that includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx#), `Thread.Sleep` pauses the current thread for a given amount of time, i.e. the thread in which the current function is run.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Threading;

public void myFunction()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Thread sleeps for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    }
}
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx